# Can I localize me with extreme precision without GPS?

Tags: android, localization, wifi, gsm

I would create an app at college for localizing me inside buildings.
Is it possible to localize me with GSM o WiFi while walking in classrooms, atriums, corridors and so on?

Comment: No. Since GPS accuracy is about 8-10 meters. WiFi don't track distance, only presence.

Comment: Even i could accept this accuracy... it doesn't work inside buildings.. Am i right?

Comment: It's not said. Sometimes I'm able to catch the satellite even inside a house or an office. It depends on reception conditions, I guess. But then the question is: how do I correctly manage the info? How can I map those results? Maybe you'd have to reverse engineer the Google Maps API.

Answer (score 0):

No Since You want location to be updated while walking and moving .GPS is recommended You can have a check [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/)

Comment: How to use GPS inside buildings?

Comment: GPS is not trustworthy in buildings, you can try to use LOcationManager.Network_Provider instead.